# How to get relative path of image for src attribute

Tags: asp.net, path

I want to display list of images on my asp.net web page.
The pictures are located in folder.
My aspx code looks like this

```
   <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvPicturePaths">
   <ItemTemplate>
     <img src="<%# Container.DataItem %>" />
   </ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

In code behind I have:

```
  private void GetImagePaths()
   {
      List<string> pathForPictures=new List<string>();
    var path=Server.MapPath("~/images/");
  foreach(var PP in Directory.GetFiles(path))
    {
    pathForPictures.Add(PP);
    }
    lvPicturePaths.DataSource=pathForPictures;
    lvPicturePath.DataBind();
 }
```

The problem  is that src attribute of the img tag need relative path, something like `localhost/images...`
Now I get something like:  `C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\images\image1.jpg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
pathForPictures.Add(
    Page.ResolveClientUrl(
        System.IO.Path.Combine(
            "~/images/",
            System.IO.Path.GetFileName(PP)
        )
    )
);
```

Or instead of doing a loop:

```
private void GetImagePaths()
{
    const string path = "~/images/";
    var pictures =
        Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(path))
            .Select(p => 
                Page.ResolveClientUrl(Path.Combine(path, Path.GetFileName(p))));
    lvPicturePaths.DataSource = pictures;
    lvPicturePath.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI - GetImagePaths doesn't actually get image paths.  Perhaps you should rename it to BindPicturePaths or have it return IEnumerable<string> and bind it elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Try Page.ResolveUrl instead of Server.MapPath

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResolveUrl`

Try this code

```
this.ResolveUrl("~/images/")
```

instead of

```
Server.MapPath("~/images/");
```

or simply try `ResolveUrl("~/images/")`

More details , see this good explanation for [Path](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne)